# URL shortener using c#

Tags: c#, url

I would like to shorten a url (e.g. http://www.abc.com/products/bag.aspx) to something like (http://short.me/bag). I have found that rules can be added to web.config to detect the short link to open the correct page. But I need a dynamic web.config. Is it a good idea to keep updating the web.config whenever a user creates the short url? Or is there a better way to do it?

I have tried `YOURLS`, `RewriteRule`, etc. All don't seems to work properly on my server. I am using a WIN server. I don't really want to use the bitly API as I would like to have my own domain in front of the link. Or is there a way to use the bitly API and still retaining my domain name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a database mapping short URLs to long URLs.

You would then create an HTTP handler that looks up the short URL in that database and redirects to the corresponding long URL.
Then, register that handler to run for all requests.

Comment: And do you make the actual shortening?

Comment: @Shimmy: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Bit.ly lets you use custom domain names now: https://bitly.com/pro/products, check out [this part of their FAQ](https://bitly.com/a/help#i_6_0)

Comment: Thanks Glenn. This helps. Will try it out.

Comment: super expensive beyond the free limit

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented my own shortlink generation program with the following approach:

1. I prepared a database to store the mapping between shortlinks and the corresponding original links.
2. I created a project that serves as a request handler, reading from the database to find the original link, and then redirecting to the original link (for example, my domain is s.thutool.com). I have made this project publicly available at: https://github.com/lelelethu/WebToolShortLink.

The function to create the link mapping is as follows:

```
public Task HandleUrl(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Path == "/")
    {
        //context.Response.Redirect(HomeLink.BasedLink);
        return context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/index.htm");
    }

    //Get link gốc
    var path = context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent().Trim('/');
    
    List<ShortLinkGetByShortLink> rsShortLinkGetByShortLink = new ShortLinkGetByShortLink(_appSetting).ShortLinkGetByShortLinkDAO(path);

    if (rsShortLinkGetByShortLink != null && rsShortLinkGetByShortLink.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rsShortLinkGetByShortLink[0].OriginalLink))
    {
            //Tang count len 1
            ShortLinkUpCountIN shortLinkUpCountIN = new ShortLinkUpCountIN
            {
                ShortLink = rsShortLinkGetByShortLink[0].ShortLink
            };
            new ShortLinkUpCount(_appSetting).ShortLinkUpCountDAO(shortLinkUpCountIN);
            context.Response.Redirect(rsShortLinkGetByShortLink[0].OriginalLink);
        }
        else
        {
            //redirect not found page
            context.Response.Redirect(HomeLink.BasedLink);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Config endpoint:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddRouting();
        services.AddTransient<IAppSetting, AppSetting>();
        services.AddTransient<ShortLinkHandleUrl>();
    })
    .Configure(app =>
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(async (endpoints) =>
        {
            endpoints.MapFallback(context =>
            {
                var appSetting = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAppSetting>();
                var shortLinkHandleUrl = new ShortLinkHandleUrl(appSetting);
                return shortLinkHandleUrl.HandleUrl(context);
            });

        });
    });
})
.Build();
```

3. Create an API project to create short links.

The API to create shortlinks is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ShortenLink")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult<object>> ShortenLink(ShortenLinkReq shortenLinkReq)
    {
        try
        {
            if (shortenLinkReq == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(shortenLinkReq.Url))
            {
                return new Models.Results.ResultApi { Success = ResultCode.ERROR, Message = MessageInfo.Url_InputEmpty };
            }

            if (!Uri.TryCreate(shortenLinkReq.Url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri result))
            {
                return new Models.Results.ResultApi { Success = ResultCode.ERROR, Message = MessageInfo.Url_IncorrectUrlFormat };
            }

            //Check if DB has current url or not
            List<ShortLinkGetByOriginalLink> rsShortLinkGetByOriginalLinkDAO = await new ShortLinkGetByOriginalLink(_appSetting).ShortLinkGetByOriginalLinkDAO(shortenLinkReq.Url);

            if (rsShortLinkGetByOriginalLinkDAO != null && rsShortLinkGetByOriginalLinkDAO.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rsShortLinkGetByOriginalLinkDAO[0].OriginalLink))
            {
                return new Models.Results.ResultApi { Success = ResultCode.OK, Result = ShortLinkConst.BasedLink + rsShortLinkGetByOriginalLinkDAO[0].ShortLink };
            }
            else
            {
                //Get MaxId
                List<ShortLinkGetMaxId> rsShortLinkGetMaxId = await new ShortLinkGetMaxId(_appSetting).ShortLinkGetMaxIdDAO();
                ShortLinkInsertIN shortLinkInsert = new ShortLinkInsertIN
                {
                    ShortLink = $"{FuncWeb.GetUrlChunk(rsShortLinkGetMaxId[0].MaxId.Value + 1)}",
                    OriginalLink = shortenLinkReq.Url,
                    ClickedCount = 0,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                };
                await new ShortLinkInsert(_appSetting).ShortLinkInsertDAO(shortLinkInsert);

                return new Models.Results.ResultApi { Success = ResultCode.OK, Result = ShortLinkConst.BasedLink + shortLinkInsert.ShortLink };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Models.Results.ResultApi { Success = ResultCode.ERROR, Message = e.Message };
        }
    }
    
    public static string GetUrlChunk(int Id)
    {
        return WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(BitConverter.GetBytes(Id)).ToLowerInvariant();
    }
```

Webtool I made: https://thutool.com/en/shortLink.
Hopefully with this way, you can also create your own shorterlink program.